# Maven Timestamp Error

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I am not able to create folder when I am using timestamp property of maven.
I have shared the pom details and the error message that got generated, however I am able to create the folder manually.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <outputFolder>C:/AutomationTestReports/${project.name}/Execution_(${timestamp})</outputFolder>
</properties>
```

In pom file of maven when I am using the above code.

As part of the build though the following error is reported:

```
[TestNG] Reporter org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter@3d8c7aca failed
org.uncommons.reportng.ReportNGException: Failed generating JUnit XML report.
    at org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter.generateReport(JUnitXMLReporter.java:83)
    at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1074)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AutomationTestReports\Demo\Execution_(2016-04-11T12:13:35Z)\xml\Script.Demo.AppTest_results.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at org.uncommons.reportng.AbstractReporter.generateFile(AbstractReporter.java:10
```

However if i remove timestamp the folder creation works fine.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <outputFolder>C:/AutomationTestReports/${project.name}</outputFolder>
</properties>
```

**Question**: How to add a timestamp to the created file in Maven?

Comment: What is the purpose of such hand brewn folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the main error is the following:

```
Caused by: ... C:\AutomationTestReports\Demo\Execution_(2016-04-11T12:13:35Z)\...
```

In Windows, you cannot have a folder containing the `:` character. I doubt you can create such a folder manually though.

To have a valid folder name, which would still meet your requirements, you should also customize another Maven property: `maven.build.timestamp.format`.

From official [Maven Introduction to POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html):

> The format of the build timestamp can be customized by declaring the property  `maven.build.timestamp.format`

Its default value is set to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`, which is not a valid Windows folder name pattern.

Hence, you could have the following:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <outputFolder>C:/AutomationTestReports/${project.name}/Execution_(${timestamp})</outputFolder>
</properties>
```

Note: the configuration above replaces the `:` character by `-` as an example, which will then generate a valid Windows folder name.

---

To better handle timezones in Maven, you could use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin) and its [`timestamp-property`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/timestamp-property-mojo.html) goal.

A simple configuration to add to your pom would be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>timestamp-property</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>build.time</name>
                <pattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss</pattern>
                <timeZone>Etc/GMT-2</timeZone>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note the `timeZone` element: here you should specify your time zone, check [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html#available-time-zones) for a full list of available valid values.

Then, in your pom your could use the `build.time` property specified above, like a maven property (`${build.time}`).

Comment: @Rajitsrajan that's an issue with timezones then. I'll add a further solution to better handle timezones then